# Check whether class members are null from Object list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, object, lambda

Is there way to check whether the particular class members are null ?

I have a class with N number of properties (members). I got to create many Objects for the class and may assign the values for those properties.. I am using List to store all the objects.

Now, I want to check whether the object in particular index from the list has any of its property as null or not set ? Can this be accomplished without using loop or checking each property manually ?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: LINQ is essentially an in-line for loop, so that might not be the solution you're looking for either. Not sure any non-LINQ method would be much more efficient, as you'll have to write a whole lot more code (which might just make it even more unmanageable). If you're storing all the properties values in a List, have you thought of possibly using the `Any` LINQ extension method? `listProperties.Any(prop => prop == null)`?

Comment: Are all of the objects in your list the same `Type`?

Comment: Yes. They all are string type..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume you have a list of items of type `A`, `listA`. Below is a LINQ expression that will find all items in the list that have any property set to `null`:

```
var output = listA.Where(a => typeof (A).GetProperties()
                                        .Any(p => p.GetValue(a) == null))
            .Select((a, index) => index)
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can check if an item at an index has any `null` properties:

```
var item = myItems[indexToCheck];
bool hasNullProperty = typeof(MyClass)
    .GetProperties()
    .Any(p => p.GetValue(item) == null);
```

Answer (score -1):

It could use some work, but here is general function you can use.  I'll be honest, I'm not sure if this violates your restriction that you don't use a loop / check each member individually (seeing as how it does both).

```
public static bool AreAnyPropertiesNull(object obj)
{
    foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        object propertyValue = prop.GetValue(obj, null);
        if (propertyValue == null)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

listOfObjects[i].HaveAnyOfPropertiesNullOrNotSet()

I see no loop here.

Comment: @JaneDoe: That's OP's rquirement: _"Now, I want to check whether the object in **particular index** from the list has any of its property as null or not set"_. The problem is that such a property would be nonsense.

Comment: @Tim: only if it has that name.  change it to IsValid and now it makes sense. I dont know what this check is for.